# Eclipse: The SVN synchronization information for 'Project' has become corrupt or does not exist

Tags: eclipse, svn, corrupt

For some days now Ecplise (Oxygen 4.7.1a) shows me question marker icons at all folders and files in the project explorer.

I figured out that this is caused by a broken SVN synchronization. Eclipse error log shows `The SVN synchronization information for 'Project' has become corrupt or does not exist.`

I use Subclipse (latest version) from Eclipse market place.

**I tried:**

- removing and reinstalling Subclipse
- removing workspace and check out SVN repo again

Still the same problem.

The curious thing is that SVN connection is ok. I can use Tortoise SVN in Windows explorer and SVN command line, but Subclipse in Eclipse does not work.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Does _Team > Refresh/Cleanup_ solve your problem? If not, if you switch to a new workspace and import the project from the old workspace, will you still see these markers? Do you have the same problem with _Subversive_?

Comment: @howlger
I am not able to select _Team -> Refresh/Cleanup_. It is disabled. I can click "Add to Version Control", but it shows the same error message as in the error log.
It is not possible to use Subversive "as it might collide with other team members".
I created a new workspace and checked out the SVN repo completely new, but still same error.

Comment: Did you already tried this?https://github.com/subclipse/archive/issues/93#event-790903734

Comment: Yes, I tried everything I've found on google :D
I'll give up now. TortoiseSVN is working and I will use it.

Comment: I'm using [Subversive](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) which is an alternative to Subclipse (both are very similar). Subversive is an Eclipse project and part of [Eclipse Oxygen](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. I tried the one thing in the link recommended by howlger, namely:

"Close Eclipse.  Open your workspace folder and then navigate to:

.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects

There will be a folder for each project, each will have a file named .syncinfo
in it.  Delete all of these files and restart Eclipse."

It did not help. But then I tried "Add to Version Control". It complained that the project is already under Version Control, but the question mark is gone and everything seems to work OK now.

Comment: When trying to add to Version Control, I get the same error message as above: "The SVN synchronization information for 'Project' has become corrupt or does not exist.".
BUT: After adding it shows me the last edit time and user beside the files in the Project Explorer. Before adding there was only 0:00:00. So it seems like it can connect, but something is really weird.

Comment: @H4rd_B4se: As described, you should delete the .syncinfo file file before trying to Add to Version control.

Comment: @Vojita I have deleted all syncinfo before ^^